# Relay no longer works on GPIO ports

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio, relay

I'm french excuse me for my english language, i works on a industrial vision processing device. I use the following components :

- Picaméra
- Raspberry Pi 3B +
- Relay : SRD-05VDC-SL-C

I work on a python script who permit to analase et recognaze a object with a Cascade.xml file. When the program recognaze a objet, he transmits the information at the relay which transmits at the light column. The code is as follows :

```
###### déclaration des Bibliotheque #####
import cv2
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
########################################

########## déclaration cascade #########
path = 'haarcascad/cascade_teste.xml'              #Chemin de la cascade
cameraNO=0                                         # entrer de la camera
objectName = 'Detecté'                             # Nom de l'objet
########################################

# déclaration format de caméra #
frameWidth= 640                      # DISPLAY WIDTH
frameHeight = 480                    # DISPLAY HEIGHT
color= (255,0,255)
########################################

###### déclaration OpenCv ##############
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(cameraNO)
cap.set(3, frameWidth)
cap.set(4, frameHeight)
########################################

########## déclaration Relais ##########
RelayPin = 3
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(RelayPin, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(RelayPin, GPIO.LOW)
########################################

def empty(a):
    pass

# Créé les barres de piste et le menu
cv2.namedWindow("Result")
cv2.resizeWindow("Result", frameWidth, frameHeight+100)
cv2.createTrackbar("Scale","Result",400,1000,empty)
cv2.createTrackbar("Neig", "Result",8,20, empty)
cv2.createTrackbar("Min Area", "Result",0, 100000, empty)
cv2.createTrackbar("Brightness","Result",180,255, empty)

# Charge les classificateurs téléchargés
cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(path)
while True:
# définir la luminosité de la caméra sous forme de valeur de trackbar
    cameraBrightness = cv2.getTrackbarPos("Brightness", "Result")
    cap.set(10, cameraBrightness)
    # obtenir l'image de la caméra et converti en niveaux de gris
    success, img = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Détecte l'object en utilisant la cascade
    scaleVal =1 +(cv2.getTrackbarPos("Scale","Result") /1000)
    neig = cv2.getTrackbarPos("Neig","Result")
    objects = cascade.detectMultiScale(gray,scaleVal,neig)
    for (x,y,w,h) in objects:
        area = w*h
        minArea = cv2.getTrackbarPos("Min Area", "Result")
        if area >minArea :
            cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),color,3)
            cv2.putText(img,objectName,(x,y-5),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL,1,color,2)
            roi_color = img[y:y+h,x:x+w]

            # Activation du relais 
            GPIO.output(RelayPin, GPIO.HIGH)
            time.sleep(1)
            GPIO.output(RelayPin, GPIO.LOW)

    cv2.imshow("Result", img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        # fin de programme
        GPIO.cleanup()
        break
```

The script work a few week and 3 weeks later after i didn't use it, he don't work.

The error who i have us : This channel is already in use, continuing anyway, Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.
I try many solution like : uninstall and reinstall the RPi, run the script in root and format the SD Card

if you have any idea it will be useful for me
thank you in advance

Comment: SRD-05VDC-SL-C is normally 5 volt and the output from the GPIO is 3,3 volt.

Comment: SRD-05VDC-SL-C is a ***relay switch***, operating at 5V, which is different from a ***relay module***, operating at 3V3 or 5V, and which consists of a couple of things, including the relay switch. Reference: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/505318/how-to-properly-use-a-relay-module-with-jd-vcc-from-arduino-raspberry.

Comment: when I look at the relay power supply on the site, it does have a logical level of communication between 3.3 and 5 V.

Comment: On https://fr.rs-online.com/web/ with the RS code :  843-0834

Comment: However, I was able to test the program on another Raspberry Pi board. It turned out that the program works (without the connection of the 24V light column). So like you said this is a connection error.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome, If what interpret what you say correctly you have a 5V relay connected directly to a GPIO pin of the RPi. If this is correct you may have a blown GPIO pin or worse. The relay you state is highly inductive and when switching off will create a reverse pulse directly into the GPIO pin of the RPi. Per the data sheet of the 5V relay requires about 70 Ma. The fact that it worked originally is possible but the relay is rated with a minimum pull in at 75% of rating in this case 5V setting the threshold at 3.75 volts. You need to isolate the coil from the RPi with a suitable device such as a MOSFET, Transistor, or Opto-Coupler. I would recommend getting a relay module (they also use them with Arduino) that has a transistor or something to isolate the coil from your port.

Comment: 251 / 5000
Résultats de traduction
This is a relay powered by the raspberry by a 5v power supply on the +, a GND on - and the GPIO03 pin on the input S of the relay.
I do not think that is put connection because the relay turns on and goes out when I use the same pins.

Answer (score 0):

That is not an error, it is a warning.

You can ignore it if you want.

https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/BasicUsage/

> It is possible that you have more than one script/circuit on the GPIO
> of your Raspberry Pi. As a result of this, if RPi.GPIO detects that a
> pin has been configured to something other than the default (input),
> you get a warning when you try to configure a script. To disable these
> warnings:
>
> GPIO.setwarnings(False)

**Are you sure you have not changed the configuration?**

GPIO 3 is I2C SCL.

If you have enabled I2C that might cause the problem you are having.

Comment: GPIO 3 is also used for other things, e.g. the dtoverlay for `gpio-shutdown`, and IIRC, is distinguished by being one of only two GPIO pins having a soldered-in pullup on the board.

Comment: I only make enabled the camera and when i use the command: (GPIO.setwarnings (False) 
the script keeps not working.

Comment: Check the GPIO.  https://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Testing